# Installing Android Studio without sudo access

Tags: sudo, android-studio

Is it possible to install the Android SDK for Android Studio. I'm working on a shared computer but I'm not on the sudoers file

Comment: could you ask for them to sudo for you or follow [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42567/how-to-install-program-locally-without-sudo-privileges)

Answer (score 0):

Follow these easy steps:

- Download `.zip` archive from  http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/2-2-1
- Unpack it and using console run `./bin/studio.sh` file